# Add Hidden Vimeo Video - Sonata Media Bundle

Tags: php, symfony, sonata-admin, sonata, sonata-media-bundle

**Hi.**

I have a video on vimeo allowed to be embedded only on specific domain. However, when trying to add it through admin panel there's an error "This value should not be empty" and "This value should not be null". I need to change my video settings to be allowed to be embedded from anywhere, then it works fine.

The problem occurs only when trying to add the video. I have no problem embedding it etc.

**Enviroment**

Symfony - 2.8.18

PHP - 7.0.32

sonata admin bundle - 3.31.*

sonata media bundle - 3.16.*

**Anyone can think of any solution or a cause?**